# Usage of "without strain" word combination

Tags: word-usage

Can word combination "without strain" be used in figurative sense, for example "He speaks English without strain." and is it literary?

Comment: Anything *can* be literary. If you mean "is its use restricted to literary contexts", no, it's perfectly ordinary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just about *anything* can be used in the figurative sense in English, and I heartily encourage you to partake of this license — provided, of course, that your figures of speech are apt and not themselves strained. The one you mentioned is fine, however; that said, I still would probably have used *difficulty* instead of *strain* there.

Comment: I think difficulty has slightly different meaning. If I'm not mistaken difficulty in this context would mean something like "I have difficulties expressing my thoughts in English", and I meant something more like "I don't have to put effort than tires me".

Comment: @elevener: Then use *effortlessly*. It sounds like more of what you want anyway.

Comment: @elevener: There's no difference in the meanings of "strain" & "difficulty" in that sentence. People physically strain to do things because they're difficult to do (eg, very heavy to lift or farther away than easily within reach) & mentally strain when a problem's difficult to solve. Speaking a foreign language sometimes provides the same circumstances: makes you tired even though you know the words & how to use them. I can say the same thing about speaking English for myself: sometimes it's difficult & sometimes it's a strain, both because it's too much effort, & I'm a prolix native speaker.

Comment: _Difficult(y)_ is generic; _strain_ is metaphorical and involves directed physical tension. _Stress_ and _strain_ are both technical terms in physics; they appear in equations and [curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress–strain_curve). So there's a gigantic meaning difference between _strain_ and _difficulty_.

Comment: @JohnLawler: No argument about the denotations of those two words, or about the connotations most of the time: they are far from being interchangeable. But please notice that I qualified what I said with "in that sentence". They are synonymous for me in that context but not in most contexts.

Comment: No problemo. Both are idioms, along with many others, for that particular conversational task. _Without straining, without (any) trouble, without (any) problem(s), without (any) difficulty/ies,_ etc.

Comment: @Bill Franke: They may be "synonymous" in OP's context, but [speaks English without difficulty](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22speaks+english+without+difficulty%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) gets 40 hits in Google Books, whereas [without strain](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22speaks+English+without+strain%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) gets none at all. Somewhat surprisingly to me, *effortlessly* only gets 5 hits (but *easily* gets 247).